# Laravel am I doing multiple queries by calling the Auth::user() multiple times in my controller

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In my controller I get the logged in user **id** and **username** like this:

```
$userId = Auth::user()->id;
$username = Auth::user()->user_name;
```

But will the above code produce two queries?
I dont understand how `Auth::user()` works behind the scene

Comment: You can do query once and store result in variable. After that you can access it whenever it required.  $user = Auth::user(); $userId = $user->id;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code generates 2 query save user in another variable.
Like this:

```
$user = Auth:user();
$userId = $user->id;
$username = $user->user_name;
```

Laravel does not store all user in session, it stores only user id. And when call user() function laravel will get user from database with saved user id.

Answer (score 2):

Auth::user() return an object with your user data from the users table.

So, if you want just one query, use :

```
$user = Auth::user();
echo $user->user_name;
```

Have a look on official doc, at Validation section.

Be sure that your user is logged before call Auth method :

```
if (Auth::check()) {
// User logged
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want reduce database query, fetch **Authenticated user** like this:

```
 $user = Auth::user():
 $id = $user->id;
 $name = $user->name;
 dd($user);
```

In laravel `Auth::user()` has all data of current authenticated user.